# math functions inside views 3

Tags: views

On my commerce site I give free shipping for users with total order over €100.
Now I would like to create a view that would say, "spend [x] euros more to get free shipping," where *[x]* is simply `100 - $total_order`.

Is there a way to accomplish this in Views, or do I need to use PHP?

Comment: where/how is $total_order defined?

Answer (score 3):

It really all depends on where $total_order is defined/declared etc.  You might be able to use the http://drupal.org/project/computed_field module to do the math and just rewrite the field with the text "spend [field] euros more...." to do it, or, if that doesn't work, or adds too much complexity, just create a views template for the field that does the math in php there and displays the field.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I am not a php programmer so any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: to create views template you don't have to be PHP programmer, you need some knowledge of Drupal. It's really simple. Look under theme in views.